# Enable mouse wheel zoom on iframe mviewer map

Tags: openlayers, javascript, mviewer

I have an interactive map designed under mviewer package in iframe on my website exactly like [here](https://kartenn.region-bretagne.fr/mviewer/demo/iframe.html). Is there a way to enable mouse wheel zoom when the pointer is over the map?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925573/javascript-mouse-wheel-zooming-for-a-web-page

Comment: @PadmanabhaChowdhury It doesn't look like something that fits my problem

Comment: OpenLayers map in an iframe works correctly here https://labs.os.uk/public/os-data-hub-examples/os-maps-api/zxy-3857-basic-map (select OpenLayers from the dropdown).  If I replace the iframe src in your html with `src="https://labs.os.uk/public/os-data-hub-examples/dist/os-maps-api/openlayers-zxy-3857-basic-map.php?auth="` from that example it also works, so presumably an issue with the css in your map when used in a iframe (as it does work standalone).  I suggest to reduce it to a basic map, then add back components to find which is breaking it.

Comment: It's obviously question of mviewer configuration. Mouse wheel zoom works in your example if you take https://kartenn.region-bretagne.fr/kartoviz/?config=demo/geobretagne.xml&mode=u as a iframe source.

Comment: @Mike I reduced the css to a basic map but zooming with the mouse wheel is still not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /demo/addons/fullscreen/fullscreen.js there is the following code:

```
// remove MouseWheelZoom if Iframe
if ( window.location !== window.parent.location ) {
    _IFrame = true;
    console.log("MVIEWER IFRAME");
   _toggleMouseWheelZoom(false);
}
```

Comment or delete this code restores the mouse wheel zoom.